# direcionamento de usuarios validados por php

Tags: php

boa tarde
eu fiz um sistema, bd ok e verificacao de loguin ok porem queria que depois de verificar o usuario ele abrisse a pagina certa para o usuario certo exemplo:
tenho 3 niveis sendo eles 0   1    2 e quero que o usuario nivel 0 abra a pagina index1.php o usuario nivel 1 abra a pagina index2.php e o usuario nivel 2 abra a pagina index3.php

```
<?php

session_start(); // Inicia a session

include "config.php";

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

if ((!$usuario) || (!$senha)){

  echo "Por favor, todos campos devem ser preenchidos! <br /><br />";

  include "index.html";

}else{

  $senha = md5($senha);

  $sql = mysql_query(

    "SELECT * FROM xxxxxx_usuarios
    WHERE usuario='{$usuario}'
    AND senha='{$senha}'
    AND ativado='1'"

  );

  $login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

  if ($login_check > 0){

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

      foreach ($row AS $key => $val){

        $$key = stripslashes( $val );

      }

      $_SESSION['usuario_id'] = $usuario_id;
      $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
      $_SESSION['sobrenome'] = $sobrenome;
      $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
      $_SESSION['nivel_usuario'] = $nivel_usuario;

      mysql_query(

        "UPDATE xxxxx_usuarios SET data_ultimo_login = now()
        WHERE usuario_id ='{$usuario_id}'"

      );

      header("Location: separador.php");


    }

  }else{

    echo "Você não pode logar-se! Este usuário e/ou senha não são válidos!<br />Por favor tente novamente!<br />";

    include "index.html";

  }

}

?>
```

onde quando ele executa o  header("Location: separador.php") direcione o usuario aberto e validado pra sua pagina certa tentei comandos com if else switch mas nunk consigo alguma ideia.

**este eh o arquivo separador.php**

```
<?php

$nivel = $_SESSION['nivel_usuario'];

if ($nivel == 0){
    header("location: /NORMAL/inicio.html");
} else if ($nivel == 1){
    header("location: /PREMIUM/index.html");
} else if ($nivel == 2){
    header("location: /ADM/index.html");
} else {
    header("location: index.html");
} 
?>
```

Comment: Como você sabe o nível do usuário? Está no banco?

Comment: Sim esta no banco descriminado

Comment: consegui resolver realocando o codigo dentro da pagina de verificacao como proposto por @João Victor Souza... agradeco pessoal

Comment: Agora que vimos sua separador.php  nota-se que faltou  session_start(); no inicio da pagina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você talvez não precise da pagina `separador.php`, você pode simplesmente usar o header para levar ao lugar certo, assim:

```
//Depois de receber o nivel do usuario na session defina a qual pagina será redirecionado
$_SESSION['nivel_usuario'] = $nivel_usuario;

if($nivel_usuario == 1){
    $pagina = "index.php";
}else if($nivel_usuario == 2){
    $pagina = "index2.php";
}else{
    $pagina = "index3.php";
}

//Depois é só concatenar a variavel pagina com o header
header("location:".$pagina.")";
```

Mas se ainda sim preferir redirecionar para a pagina `separador.php`, pode fazer o seguinte lá:

```
$tipo = $_SESSION['nivel_usuario'];

if($tipo == 1){
    header("location: index.php");
}else if($tipo == 2){
    header("location: index2.php");
}else{
    header("location: index3.php");
}
```

Comment: desculpe minha ignorancia mas neste ultimo nao ia direcionar direto para o index3

Comment: Ele só iria redirecionar para **index3.php** caso o tipo não fosse igual a 1 ou igual a 2

Comment: Você também pode adicionar um ultimo **if** para verificar se é igual a 3, porém não creio que seja necessário, ficaria assim o ultimo: `}else if($tipo == 3){ header("location: index3.php"); }`

Comment: Estou usando **if** encadeado ou **else if**, caso não conheça pode ler mais sobre na documentação do php : [Estrutura else if](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: bom dia esta opcal dentro do separador somente encaminha para o tipo 2 mesmo eu sendo tipo 1 kkkk tava perdidao mesmo com pouco conhecimento em php

Comment: Bom dia @EduardoSaraiva, tente colocar aspas na comparação pra ver se vai, assim: `($tipo == "1")`, faça com todos

Comment: coloquei e jogou direto para o erro

Comment: Você esta usando `session_start();` na pagina **separador.php** ?? se não, tente isso

Answer (score 1):

> Após o autor ter publicado a página `separador.php` nota-se a ausência de `session_start()`

coloque session_start(); no inicio da separador.php que vai dar certo

```
<?php

session_start();

$nivel = $_SESSION['nivel_usuario'];

if ($nivel == 0){
    header("location: /NORMAL/inicio.html");
} else if ($nivel == 1){
    header("location: /PREMIUM/index.html");
} else if ($nivel == 2){
    header("location: /ADM/index.html");
} else {
    header("location: index.html");
} 
?>
```

> **Se não colocar** `session_start();` vai cair na condicional `0` independente se é no `if` ou qualquer `else if`

```
<?php

$nivel = $_SESSION['nivel_usuario'];

if ($nivel == 1){
    header("location: /NORMAL/inicio.html");
} else if ($nivel == 2){
    header("location: /PREMIUM/index.html");
} else if ($nivel == 0){

    /******* Vai redirecionar para esta página *******/
    header("location: /ADM/index.html");
    /************************************************/

} else {
    header("location: index.html");
} 
?>
```

### Porque cai na condicional `== 0`?

Porque se a sessão não for iniciada `$_SESSION['nivel_usuario']` não existe <sub>- verifique com var_dump($_SESSION['nivel_usuario']) -</sub> e `$nivel` vai ser `NULL`, portanto, para o PHP  `NULL == 0` ***por conseguinte `$nivel == 0` é true***

---

---

> Outra solução seria alocar o código

```
$nivel = $_SESSION['nivel_usuario'];

if ($nivel == 0){
    header("location: /NORMAL/inicio.html");
} else if ($nivel == 1){
    header("location: /PREMIUM/index.html");
} else if ($nivel == 2){
    header("location: /ADM/index.html");
} else {
    header("location: index.html");
}
```

> dentro da pagina de verificação no lugar de `header("Location: separador.php");`

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss e Guilherme Nascimento, agora a resposta ficou supimpa!

Answer (score 0):

Direcionar para a página, e caso algum valor diferente, abre uma página de erro/acesso negado:

```
$nivel = $_SESSION['nivel_usuario'];

if ($nivel == 1){
    header("location: index1.php");
} else if($nivel == 2){
    header("location: index2.php");
} else if($nivel == 3){
    header("location: index3.php");
} else {
    header("location: erro.php");
}
```

---

Você pode usar qualquer outra estrutura de condição. Simplesmente filtrar e direcionar com o [header](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php).